# Can anyone help me proving this bi-conditional statement, I'm stuck after converting by completing the square method

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $ a \in\mathbb R $, Prove that :
( $ \forall x \in \mathbb R, x^2 + ax +a > 0)$ if and only if $ (0<a<4)$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a quadratic polynomial, with the coefficient of $x^2$ equal to 1. For it to be always positive it suffices that its Discriminant is negative.